# Meteor 1.3 populate select from collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to just populate a select from the db. The select works with fix options but not with data from the collection.

For now, I have not removed autopublish package yet as I'm learning.

It looks like the collection is not visible. If I type CarBrands.find() in the browser's console (Chrome) it says: "Uncaught ReferenceError: CarBrands is not defined".

I consider I have not to publish and subscribe anything at this point.

I am following [the todos tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/collections) but with my own idea instead of the todo list. Also, I am using meteor 1.3 (with the imports and all that stuff, as the tutorial shows)

Any help is more than welcome. I've posted this same question in the meteor's [forum](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-1-3-populate-select-from-db/23229) and there you can see the code as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: double check the path in `import { CarBrands } from '../api/utilities.js';`

Comment: @AnkurSoni that's pure Meteor 1.3 way. I am watching the tutorial I mentioned to do what I want to do

Comment: @Nimir I just checked it. It's alright. Otherwise the browser's console would show me an error

Answer (score 0):

As I am using selectize.js I searched for the issue and I found a kind of answer in [here](https://github.com/chhib/meteor-selectize-bootstrap-3/issues/2). Yet I am not 100% happy but at least its behaviour is better than before